# Mysqli is messing up my while loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

I am trying to retrieve a list of people from a database. I've done this about a thousand times with mysql. I just recently switch to mysqli and my method for retrieving people isn't working properly.

Heres my code:

```
$people = '';
$get_people = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id');
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_people)) {
    $fn = $rows['first_name'];
    $ln = $rows['last_name'];
    $img = $rows['picture'];

    $people .= '<li>';
    $people .= "<img src='".$img."' style='width: 20px; height: 20px;'> ";
    $people .= "<span>".$fn." ".$ln."</span>";
    $people .= '</li>';

    echo $people;
}
```

My while loop repeats the first entry of the database twice. Example:

- [image] Joseph Warren
- [image] Joseph Warren
- [image] Bob Robertson
- [image] Joseph Warren
- [image] Bob Robertson
- [image] Phil Sneider

([image] is the picture I pulled from the database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `$people` to outside your loop. When you call it inside, it will display what has already been stored from the previous loop.

```
$people = '';
$get_people = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id LIMIT 2');
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_people)) {
    $fn = $rows['first_name'];
    $ln = $rows['last_name'];
    $img = $rows['picture'];

    $people .= '<li>';
    $people .= "<img src='".$img."' style='width: 20px; height: 20px;'> ";
    $people .= "<span>".$fn." ".$ln."</span>";
    $people .= '</li>';
}

echo $people;
```

I would also suggest that you use a column list in your `SELECT` for best practice.

Comment: @user3112869 each time you iterate over the result, you store the result in `$people`. For each time that you iterate and output `$people`, it will contain all previous iterations *unless* you move the `echo` to **outside** the loop

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my old comment. I thought you were referring to when I first called the $people variable at the top